# How do I make the following image in swift programmatically

Tags: swift

[image]

How do I make the this image in swift programmatically, when I tried it myself, I was able to do the following
[image]

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 10, right: 30)
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15
collectionViews = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
guard let collectionView = collectionViews else { return }
scrollView.addSubview(collectionView)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.delaysContentTouches = true
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.register(MenusCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MenusCell.identifier)
collectionView.backgroundColor = .red
collectionView.top(collectionViewTop?.bottomAnchor ?? scrollView.topAnchor, 2)
collectionView.left(view.leftAnchor, 0)
collectionView.right(view.rightAnchor, 0)
collectionView.bottom(view.bottomAnchor, -50)
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: You will need to create a custom UICollectionLayout for this. You can’t just use FlowLayout like this.

Comment: In SwiftUI you could use https://github.com/paololeonardi/WaterfallGrid for the pinterest-style waterfall grid. I don't know a good example for UIKit (I nevere worked with it), maybe this could help you: https://github.com/KyoheiG3/GridView. Or maybe you can find something here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grid